# Что значит "через час" и "через каждый час"?

Tags: значение

Это каждый час или каждый второй?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Через час** обозначает в следующем часу примерно в ту же минуту. Например, если сейчас 10:30, и вы говорите: "Встретимся через час", то вы планируете встречу на 11:30 плюс-минус минут 5.

> Обратите внимание, здесь не как с остановками. Если стоя на остановке 1 или на пути к остановке 2, вы скажете, что выходите через одну, это значит, что вы выйдете на третьей.

**Через каждый час** обозначает делать что-то по началу каждого часа, т.е. начинать или совершать действие каждые 60 минут. `Через каждый час` [синонимично](https://hinative.com/ru/questions/14852029) `каждый час`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Я, конечно, на rusStackExchange новый участник, как и вы, но на StackOverflow принято принимать ответы, решившие проблему путем клика по галочке! :)

Comment: Извините, я не знала.

Comment: Ничего страшного, но вы либо не нажали, либо не попали по кнопке

Comment: "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга". Вот, что пишет, когда я нажимаю на кнопку. Русский язык мне не родной, но все равно немного понимаю. :)

Comment: А вы нажимаете на стрелочку вверх или галочку?

Comment: Теперь нажала на галочку. Надеюсь, что теперь все в порядке. :)